# What would be the RegEx to solve the following problem?

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the RegEx to output the following result:-

```
d = 1000 / 280;
console.log(d);
```

Output:

```
3.5714285714285716
```

But I want to output only the first 3 digits including the dot. (Or can say 4 character with the dot)
example:-

```
3.57
```

**Update:** It's possible to solve this by using `Math.floor`
e.g.

```
d = 1000 / 280;
d = Math.floor(d * 100) / 100;
```

But I was actually looking for a regular expression based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need a regex?

Simply use `Math.floor`:

```js
d = 1000 / 280;
d = Math.floor(d * 100) / 100; // Precision: 2 digits
console.log(d);
```

---

If you still want to do it with a regex, here's what you're looking for (this will work for any number, negative includes):

```js
d = 1000 / 280;
d = d.toString().replace(/^(-?\d+\.\d{2}).*/, '$1');
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Thanks but I was actualy looking for the RegEx. If its possible with the RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `Math.round` here:

```js
var d = 1000 / 280;
d = Math.round(d * 100) / 100;
console.log(d);
```

If you really wanted a regex solution, here it is:

```js
var d = 1000 / 280;
output = (d+"").replace(/^(\d+\.\d{2}).*$/, "$1");
console.log(output);
```

The regex approach I used is to first convert the decimal number to a string.  Then, capture the digits before the decimal place and two after the decimal place, replacing only with this captured quantity.

Comment: Thanks but I was actualy looking for the RegEx. If its possible with the RegEx.

Comment: @EmilyTaylor Check the updated answer for a regex option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `toFixed` Function
Like:

```
var num = 2.475467899;
num.toFixed(2);
```

That will return
    2.47

`toFixed(2)` here `2` is number of decimal point you required.